# Check if multiple columns are identical in r (with missing data)

Tags: r, vector, missing-data, equality

I am trying to determine if multiple columns are identical to each other in R.  Each variable contains string data.  An example might look something like this. There is some missing data in the file.

```
            df <- data.frame (id  = c(1:9),
                              var1  = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var2  = c("a", "b", NA, "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var3  = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var4  = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var5  = c("a", NA, "c", "b", "a", NA, "c", "a", "b"),
                              var6  = c("a", NA, "c", "a", "c", NA, "c", "a", "b"),
                              var7  = c("a", NA, "c", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var8  = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var9  = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c", "a", "c", "a", "b"),
                              var10  = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c", NA, "c", "a", "b")
     )
```

I want to identify any changes differences across the variables while ignoring missing data (e.g., in id 4, all vars are "a" except for var4 and var5 which are b).
I am trying to export a dataframe that shows the id and all the variables.

```
output
id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10
4     a    a    a    b    b    a    a    a    a    a
5     a    a    a    a    a    c    c    c    c    c
...
```

I could create a flag variable for each individual circumstance that could happen.

```
df$flag [df$var1 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var4 == "a" & df$var5 == "a" & df$var6 == "a" & df$var7 == "a" & df$var8 == "a" & df$var9 == "a" & df$var10 == "b"]<- 1
df$flag [df$var1 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var4 == "a" & df$var5 == "a" & df$var6 == "a" & df$var7 == "a" & df$var8 == "a" & df$var9 == "a" & df$var10 == "c"]<- 1
df$flag [df$var1 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var4 == "a" & df$var5 == "a" & df$var6 == "a" & df$var7 == "a" & df$var8 == "a" & df$var9 == "b" & df$var10 == "b"]<- 1
df$flag [df$var1 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var2 == "a" & df$var4 == "a" & df$var5 == "a" & df$var6 == "a" & df$var7 == "a" & df$var8 == "a" & df$var9 == "c" & df$var10 == "c"]<- 1
    ...
```

This does not seem like an ideal solution as there are too many circumstances I would need to code for, many of which might not even occur in the data frame.

I tried using unique, but this just identifies the various patterns.  I would still need to code for each of them.  Since the data is string, I can't use var().  On a smaller scale, when there are just two variables, I could use == or identical().  I'm not sure how to approach this with a large number of variables.

Comment: Does `id` identify the rows are are there repeated values within `id`? Are you trying to do this by row or by `id`?

Comment: by id.  In the dataset I am working on, I have a few different variables that I use for the id.  I was able to modify the code below to account for the extra id variables.  .by = c ("id", "second_id_variable", "third_id_variable").  The dplyr solution worked.  I found the documentation for n_distinct (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/n_distinct.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(n_distinct(c_across(starts_with("var")), na.rm = T) > 1, .by = id)
```

A way to do this by row in base R would be:

```
df[apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) nlevels(factor(x))) > 1,]
```

**Output**

```
  id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10
1  4    a    a    a    b    b    a    a    a    a     a
2  5    a    a    a    a    a    c    c    c    c     c
3  6    a    a    b    b <NA> <NA>    b    a    a  <NA>
```